# Button is not showing

Tags: javascript

When the page loades, it has my list and a show and hide button. However when i go down the list its suppose to display pictures and some text. However my buttons (hide and show) disappear. How to make them appear even when this occurs? 
Thanks for the help

```
        function imagechange(image)
        {
            mangaimage.innerHTML = "<img src='mangalist/" + image + "small.jpg'/>";
            mangasummary.innerHTML = changetext(mangasum[image],95);
                            readmanga.href = mangasite[image];

        }

        function changetext(text,num)
        {
            numChar = num;
            arrayWord = text.split(" ");
            str = "";
            strArray = new Array();
            newtext = "";
                for ( i = 0; i < arrayWord.length; i ++)
                {
                    if (str.length + arrayWord[i].length >= numChar)
                    {

                        newtext += str + "<br />";
                        str = ""
                    }

                    if (str.length + arrayWord[i].length <= numChar)
                    {   
                        str += arrayWord[i] + " ";
                    }

                    if (i == arrayWord.length-1)
                    {
                        newtext += str+ "<br />";
                    }

                }

            return newtext;
        }


    function hide()
        {
        document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "none";
```

```
            <tr>
                <td id = "mim" colspan ="2">

                <span id = "mangaim">
                </span>
                </td>


                <td id = "min">
                Manga List:<br />

                <select id= "listm" size = "15" onchange = "imagechange(this.value)">
                    <option value = "onepiece" id = "po"> One Piece </option>
                    <option value = "naruto" id = "po" > Naruto </option>
                    <option value = "bleach" id = "po"> Bleach </option>
                    <option value = "gintama" id = "po"> Gintama </option>
                    <option value = "nisekoi" id = "po"> Nisekoi </option>
                    <option value = "worldtrigger" id = "po"> World Trigger </option>
                    <option value = "psi" id = "po"> PSI Kusuo Saiki </option>
                    <option value = "ironknight" id = "po"> Iron Knight </option>
                    <option value ="stealth" id = "po"> Stealth Symphony </option>
                    <option value = "illegalrare" id = "po"> Illegal Rare </option>
                    <option value = "haikyu" id = "po"> Haikyu!! </option>
                    <option value = "kuroko" id = "po"> Kuroko No Basket </option>
                    <option value = "assassin" id = "po"> Assassination Classroom </option>
                    <option value = "shoku" id = "po"> Shokugeki no Soma</option>
                    <option value = "toriko" id = "po"> Toriko </option>
                </select>


                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2">
                    <span id="ms">
                </td>
            </br>



    <button onclick = "hide()">Hide</button>
    <button onclick = "showlist()">Show List</button>   

    <script>
    mangaimage = document.getElementById("mangaim");
    mangasummary = document.getElementById("ms");
    readmanga = document.getElementById("rm");
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy or messy code layout. first time pasting code on stackoverflow.

Comment: I would suggest taking all of this code, and deleting everything from it that is not contributing to your button not showing. Once you can reproduce the issue of the button not showing in a subset of the code shown here you will probably get better results in the form of answers. As it stands, this is basically a "code dump". While people answering questions here may volunteer their time, that is no reason to waste their time on purpose like this.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. slimmed down the code and editted it. thanks!

Comment: You appear to be declaring  mangasum as an array and then using it like an object.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Robert, No reason in particular, it was a way i did it and it worked. Im suppose to be going down the list (manga list) and when clicked on a manga like lets say Naruto, it displays a description and picture of the manga.

Comment: Your element `<span id="ms">` is not closed. The result of using .innerHTML on this element seems to be replacing the rest of the page.

Comment: Fixed the span. but how would i change it so that it displays both the list, (which displays my image/description) and my buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Awesome App Beta

The corrected code below works. One potential problem was declaring an array and trying to use it like an object:

```
var mangasum = new Array();
mangasum["onepiece"] = "some string";
```

You can actually access arrays using an associative index. As MDN says:

> Some people think that you shouldn't use an array as an associative
>   array. In any case, you can use plain objects instead, although doing
>   so comes with its own caveats. See the post Lightweight JavaScript
>   dictionaries with arbitrary keys as an example.

Reference: [MDN Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

So the error was likely a combination of minor syntax errors and a lot of malformed html. Thanks to browser robustness it limped along regardless. Despite the ugly code, I came to admire OP's willingness to write it himself and at least try ... which is more than I can say about many posts on SO.

I leave it to OP to finish the details and make this an awesome app:

**Run Snippet to Test** (images omitted)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Demo</title>
   </head>    
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td id = "mim" colspan ="2">
               <span id = "mangaim">
               </span>
            </td>
            <td id = "min">
               Manga List:<br />
               <select id= "listm" size = "15" onchange = "imagechange(this.value)">
                  <option value = "onepiece" id = "po"> One Piece </option>
                  <option value = "naruto" id = "po" > Naruto </option>
                  <option value = "bleach" id = "po"> Bleach </option>
                  <option value = "gintama" id = "po"> Gintama </option>
                  <option value = "nisekoi" id = "po"> Nisekoi </option>
                  <option value = "worldtrigger" id = "po"> World Trigger </option>
                  <option value = "psi" id = "po"> PSI Kusuo Saiki </option>
                  <option value = "ironknight" id = "po"> Iron Knight </option>
                  <option value = "stealth" id = "po"> Stealth Symphony </option>
                  <option value = "illegalrare" id = "po"> Illegal Rare </option>
                  <option value = "haikyu" id = "po"> Haikyu!! </option>
                  <option value = "kuroko" id = "po"> Kuroko No Basket </option>
                  <option value = "assassin" id = "po"> Assassination Classroom </option>
                  <option value = "shoku" id = "po"> Shokugeki no Soma</option>
                  <option value = "toriko" id = "po"> Toriko </option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan = "2">
               <span id="ms">
            </td>
            
         </tr>
      </table>
    
      <button onclick = "hide()">Hide</button>
      <button onclick = "showlist()">Show List</button>   
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
          
         var mangasum = {
             onepiece : "Gold Rogeet coveerso", 
             bleach : "Ichigo Kurosaki has always be", 
             stealth : "In a world where elves, dwar", 
             naruto : "In the village of Konohagakure", 
             kuroko : "Kuroko is a member from the l",
             gintama : "The story focuses on an ecc",
             nisekoi : "Raku Ichijou may be the heir to a y", 
             assassin : "A weird class kicks off in the super",
             shoku : "Yukihira Souma's dream is to become a fu", 
             worldtrigger : "A gate to another dimension has burs",
             haikyu : "A chance event triggerer",
             illegalrare : "Supernatural creatures live alongside",
             psi : "Saiki Kusuo has a wide array of superpowers at his",
             ironknight : "A boy with a body like steel encounters the"
         }
         
         function imagechange(image) {
             mangaimage.innerHTML = "<img src='mangalist/" + image + "small.jpg'>";
             mangasummary.innerHTML = changetext(mangasum[image], 95);
             readmanga.href = mangasite[image];
         }
         
         function changetext(text,num) {
             numChar = num;
             arrayWord = text.split(" ");
             str = "";
             strArray = new Array();
             newtext = "";
             for ( i = 0; i < arrayWord.length; i ++) {
                 if (str.length + arrayWord[i].length >= numChar) {
                     newtext += str + "<br />";
                     str = ""
                 }
         
                 if (str.length + arrayWord[i].length <= numChar) {   
                     str += arrayWord[i] + " ";
                 }
         
                 if (i == arrayWord.length-1) {
                     newtext += str+ "<br />";
                 }
         
             }
         
             return newtext;
         }
         
         
         function hide() {
             document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "none";
         }
         
         function showlist() {
             document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "block";
         }
         
         
         var mangaimage = document.getElementById("mangaim");
         var mangasummary = document.getElementById("ms");
         var readmanga = document.getElementById("rm");
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment Robert! I was trying to get the code up and running before cleaning up the code/making it presentable and css. Been learning this for a year so far but still not good at it. Thanks for the help Robert! Appreciated!